# R: How to calculate Chi square test on every column?

Tags: r, function

I have a table with more than 50 columns. I would like to perform a Chi-square test on every column of my data. But converting each variable into a freq table and then applying `chisq.test` seems very costly:

```
tabl_dat <- table(data$q_CEO)
chisq.test(tabl_dat)
```

How can I improve this algorithm? Is there any functions that perform Chi-square on multiple columns?

Sample:

```
structure(list(q_CEO = structure(c(1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("A man", 
"A woman", "Any (incl. other genders)"), class = "factor"), q_Salesman = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("A man", "Any (incl. other genders)"
), class = "factor"), q_Housekeeper = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = c("A woman", "Any (incl. other genders)"), class = "factor"), 
    q_Painter = structure(c(1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
    1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("A man", 
    "A woman", "Any (incl. other genders)"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-37L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: You can use apply over columns!

Comment: @LisandroDiMeo I tried, but have not succeeded ```apply(data, 2, chisq.test(table(data)))```

Comment: it's becauase you need to pass a funcion. I think it should be apply(data, 2, chisq.test)

Comment: also tired this one, error pops up ```wrong 'type'```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Lisandro Di Meo!

First, I used `lapply` function over my columns:

```
table_mw <- lapply(data, table)
```

Then I used `lapply` and specified `chisq.test`:

```
table_mw <- lapply(data, table) %>%
            lapply(., chisq.test)
```

And got the desirable answer.